# ASP.NET MVC Model.Where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am create a view that has two tables - one for admin and one for member. I am stuck trying to separate the users into each table

This is my view code currently (Trying to filter 'admin' users for the code below)

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>

@foreach (var item in Model.Where(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

    <tr>
        <td class="c">
            @item.UserName
        </td>

        <td class="c">
            @item.EmailConfirmed
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

However I am getting an error with this - 
    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func'

I would like all the users that are in the role 'admin' to be on one table and all the users that are in the role 'member' to be on another. How do i go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: `IsInRole` method returns `true` or `false`. But the `Where` method expecting a func expression.

Answer (score 3):

The `.Where()` extension method isn't just expecting a `bool`, it's expecting a `Func<T, bool>` expression which *returns* a `bool`.  Take a look at the examples in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx).

In your attempt, `User.IsInRole("Admin")` would execute immediately and pass its result to `.Where()`.  But by using a `Func<T, bool>` instead, the `.Where()` method would re-apply that expression to every element in the collection to use as a filter for those elements.

Which would look more like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Where(u => u.User.IsInRole("Admin")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however there is a slight error when I tried this - 'IdentityUser' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityUser' could be found

Comment: @Waled.Nur74: Then what exactly are you searching for in that collection?  What are you trying to filter?  `IdentityUser` does have a `Roles` property, perhaps you want to filter on the existence of something there?  It depends on what's in the `Roles` collection.  If it's strings, that might look something like: `Model.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains("Admin"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda expression needs a variable to work:

```
Model.Where(user => user.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

Comment: getting this error - 'IdentityUser' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityUser' could be found

Comment: @Waled.Nur74 What you should do is do your filtering in your controller (or repository) and return two lists. Because you will need to filter on navigation properties of your user object and they might not be filled once you selected them.

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet. It should work :

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(u=>{return u.User.IsInRole("Admin");})
    {

        <tr>
            <td class="c">
                @item.UserName
            </td>

            <td class="c">
                @item.EmailConfirmed
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use a simple `if` statement inside loop's body?

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   // render HTML
}
```

This, even will be a little bit faster than using `LINQ`..

BTW, a view should not perform this kind of logic operations .. We use MVC for separation of concerns ..